# How to query friend of a friend of a friend in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following schema:

I would like to find all friends of a friends of a friends of a user whose name is "John". This is the first time that I will be performing nested queries like that, so I seek help!

For example, I have the following data:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      User_ID        |     Name         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         Jon      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         Matt     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         Kat      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         Sam      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          5          |         Eli      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          6          |         Kay      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

And in the other table I got:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|  User_friend_ID     |     user_id      |     friend_id    | 
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         1        |        2         | 
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         2        |        3         | 
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         3        |        4         | 
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         4        |        2         | 
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          5          |         4        |        3         | 
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          6          |         4        |        5         | 
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

The result of the query shuold be names of the users with ID's:

```
2,3,4,5
```

Comment: I am using MS SQL with SQL Server if that is what you are asking :)

Comment: Can you please share some sample data and expected result as text/DDL,DML

Comment: What do you want the result set to look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Will you always be looking for the 3rd level friend, or do you want to easily cope with more complex relationships?  Also, are there any restraints (i.e. a friend it also a friend of a friend of a friend, since you are your friend's friend, so the relationship can loop back from them to you, then back to them again; should that count / what about if your friend's friend is also a friend of yours)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Juan Romero and @dasblinkenlight have already given great answers to this.  Below are a couple of more complex options should they be required.  i.e. allowing you to easily switch between friend-of-friend-of-friend to friend-of-friend-of-friend-of-friend with no recoding, and to exclude a friend-of-friend-of-friend where they're also a friend-of-friend.

```
declare @userId long = 1 --whichever user's friends you're looking for
, @degreesOfSeparation = 3 --friend of a friend of a friend
, @name nvarchar(32) = 'John'

; with relationshipCte as 
(

    --get our patient 0 (the user whose friends we're looking for)
    select 0 degreesOfSeperation
    , user_id
    from [user]
    where user_id = @userId

    full outer join 

    --for every friend, pull back that friend's friends
    select degreesOfSeperation + 1
    , friend_id
    from relationshipCte cte
    inner join [Friends] f 
        on f.user_id = cte.user_id
        --and not f.friend_id = @userId --include this if we want to exclude the original user as being a friend of a friend (and similar)

)
select *
from relationshipCte cte
inner join [user] u
on u.user_id = cte.user_id
where cte.degreesOfSeperation = @degreesOfSeperation
and u.Name = @name
order by u.user_id
option (maxrecursion 10) --never go more than 10 relationships away from patient 0 (arguably a reasonable assumption given https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation)
```

If you want to avoid including any friends who are closer than 3 degrees of separateion (e.g. you're friends with Jim and Jane; Jim and Jane are friends with one another; thuse they're both friends, and also friends of friends), use the below:

```
declare @userId long = 1 
, @degreesOfSeparation long = 3
, @i long = 1
, @name nvarchar(32) = 'John'

declare @relationships table 
(
    user_id long
    , closestRelation long
)
insert @relationships (user_id, closestRelation) values (@userId, 0) --insert patient 0
while @i <= @degreesOfSeperation
begin
    insert @relationships (user_id, closestRelation) --insert friends
    select f.friend_id, @i
    from @relationships
    inner join Friends f
    on f.user_id = u.user_id
    where not exists (select top 1 1 from @relationships r where r.user_id = f.friend_id) --exclude friends already in our list
   SET @i = @i + 1
end

select *
from @relationships r
inner join [user] u
on u.user_id = r.user_id
where r.closestRelation = @degreesOfSeperation
and u.Name = @name
order by u.user_id
```

NB: I've not had a chance to run the above SQL; but hopefully should work as stated...

Comment: Given the update to the requirements by the OP, a recursive CTE (as in this answer) would be the right way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Start with querying a friend (`f0`):

```
select friend.*
from User friend
join Friends f0 on friend.user_id=f0.friend_id
where f0.user_id=my_user_id
```

Expand it to do a friend-of-a-friend `f1` by adding a second join:

```
select friend.*
from User friend
join Friends f1 on friend.user_id=f1.friend_id
join Friends f0 on f1.user_id=f0.friend_id
where f0.user_id=my_user_id
```

Adding the third join to `f2` will give you a friend-of-a-friend-of-a-friend. You should be able to complete this exercise by following the two examples above.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT ff.user_id, uf.name FROM [User] u
INNER JOIN [Friends] f ON u.user_id = f.user_id --= to find his friends
INNER JOIN [Friends] ff ON f.friend_id = ff.user_id --= f.friend_id is his friends
INNER JOIN [User] uf ON ff.friend_id = uf.user_id --= ff.friend_id is friends of his friends
WHERE u.name = 'John'
GROUP BY ff.user_id,uf.name
```

It selects the id of the friend of the friend of the friend as well as his name.

Comment: NB: the person is their own friend's friend; so will be included in the ff query unless explicitly blocked (i.e. `and ff.user_id != u.user_id`).  Not sure on user's requirements, but you may wish to avoid such situations (the same scenario may also exist for `uf` depending on relationships)

Comment: This limits the number of levels to two, doesn't it?